# Replacing string with a variable in php

Tags: variables

I have following code in my plugin of Wordpress:

```
wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue[idinfo],
            'index1' => $myoptionValue[id1],
            'index2' => $myoptionValue[id2]
            )
        );
```

I want to replace

```
'index1' => $myoptionValue[id1],
'index2' => $myoptionValue[id2]
```

with

```
for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
        {
            $arguments .= ',"index"'.$i.'=>'.$myoptionValue[id.$i];
        }
```

So that I have

```
        wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue[idinfo]
            $arguments
            )
        );
```

Apparently I'm thinking it might be as simple as this, but it isn't, where is my mistake?

EDIT:

full code:

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'menu.php');
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'getuser.php');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ffd_load_scripts' );

function ffd_load_scripts()
{
$myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
$myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

$arguments = array();
for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
{
    $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
}

wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
    );

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
```

}

Comment: I strongly suspect micro-optimisation is at work here, `$myoptionValue[id2]` also looks like it would generate a PHP fatal error, do you mean `$myoptionValue[$id2]`? To truly condense this down you need to show more of the surrounding code

Comment: edited it in the op

Comment: Where are `idinfo`, `id1` and `id2` defined? Unless these are constants somewhere this is invalid PHP, I would expect your original code to generate fatal errors

Comment: They come from a database. It is valid PHP because it is working now. But now I have 2 arguments (index1 and index2) and if there is index115 I hardly can code all this so I want to iterate over it.

Comment: They aren't defined anywhere though, please show where the values come from, without knowing how they're defined, or what their values are, it's incredibly difficult to refactor your code. Are they constants? are they produced using a DEFINE statement? Even if you think those details aren't relevant, please provide them

Comment: They are defined on my options page of my plugin, which stores them in the database. $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
        $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption ); This code gets them for me from the database.

Comment: I gathered that, but where does id1 and idinfo come from? Are you sure you don't mean `$myoptionValue['idinfo']` or `$myoptionValue[$idinfo]` ? Where `$myoptionValue` comes from is very clear, but idinfo and id1 are being used as keys to access this array but they aren't defined anywhere, they're pulled out of thin air

Comment: i have put quots around them, it is still working (like before). Now, how can I iterate over it and generate the string?

Comment: Thanks, now we know those are meant to be string literals it's possible to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 valid ways of defining a string, [see this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886899/alternative-way-to-write-string-literals-in-php-without-or)

However in your case there is a special exception provided by PHP. Most users are unaware of it however, and it does leave ambiguities, as it's no longer possible to tell a string literal, a constant, or a define apart, making it very difficult for other programmers to read your code ( e.g. yourself in 9 months time ).

So your code:

```
for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
{
    $arguments .= ',"index"'.$i.'=>'.$myoptionValue[id.$i];
}
```

Is trying to append a string to the end of an array, which doesn't work. Arrays aren't strings, and you can only use the `.=` and `.` operators on strings. Also `$myoptionValue[id.$i]` violates the special case situation as the expression is now ambiguous ( does it mean 'id.$i', 'id'.$i, or "id.$i"? )

To add an item to an array you need to do one of the following:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['key'] = 'value';
$arr[] = 'value without a key';
array_push( $arr, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', etc... );
```

So your loop should be:

```
for ( $i=1; $i <= $myoptionValue['fieldcount']; $i++ ) {
    $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i ];
}
```

Comment: This does not work, I have updated my code in the OP.

Comment: How does it not work? What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened? Can you verify that `$myoptionValue[fieldcount]` contains the expected value? Can you update your question with a full debug output of the contents of `$myoptionValue`?